# JS - Run the promises in order with $q.when(), how do I add finally?

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, promise, q

I am generating objects using external source with intention of processing them callback style. Unfortunately these callbacks can chain way beyond the stack limit of a browser and I have to keep in mind the worst case scenario of 500 for IE.

I have rewritten my code using $q.when

```
   $scope.combinations.forEach(function(combination) {
        chain = chain.then(function() {
         return generateConfiguration(combination);
        });
    });
```

generateConfiguration if a function that returns a promise. It all works just fine, but what I want to do is add **finally()** at the end of the chain.

What I did so far is to have a tracker inside generateConfiguration that recognizes the last combination and triggers what should have been triggered by **finally**.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Just write `chain.finally(…)` after the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

You're creating a promise **chain**, so if you want a **single** `finally` for the chain, just add it at the end **after** building it with that `forEach`:

```
// ...your forEach here, then:
chain.finally(/*...*/);
```

If you want a `finally` on **each** promise from `generateConfiguration`, either give yourself a wrapper function to do that, or do it inside the `forEach` callback.

```
$scope.combinations.forEach(function(combination) {
    chain = chain.then(function() {
        return generateConfiguration(combination).finally(/*...*/); // <== 
    });
});
```

---

Side note: There's a more idiomatic way to build that chain, via `reduce`:

```
var chain = $scope.combinations.reduce(function(chain, combination) {
    return chain.then(function() {
        return generateConfiguration(combination);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Adding a final `finally` (option #1 above):

```
var chain = $scope.combinations.reduce(function(chain, combination) {
        return chain.then(function() {
            return generateConfiguration(combination);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve())
    .finally(function() {
        // ...do stuff here...
    });
```

Comment: @TJ thanks your initial solution works. Not sure why I haven't just tried it. About your suggestion, why is it better than my solution?

Comment: @CountGradsky: It isn't *better* other than that it's the idiom for doing that which has arisen over the past 3-4 years. :-) Idioms are "good" or "better" only in that they're readily recognizable to other programmers who also know the idiom, making the code easy to understand.

Comment: Not a native speaker, had to google "idiomatic" :) I'll have your suggestion as a comment if you dont mind

Comment: @CountGradsky: Your English is very good, I didn't notice it wasn't your native language. I'm afraid I don't understand the second half of your comment above, though.

Comment: I'll have that snippet commented above my initial piece of code in case I move away from $q.when()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: inject `$q` (i.e. the promise framework) and rew-rite to

```
$q.all($scope.combinations.map(function(combination) {
   return generateConfiguration(combination);
})).finally(function(res) {
   /* ... */
});
```

That way, you'll also fire off all generateConfiguration(s) in parallel (at least as many as possible - like there 's a limit on e.g. XHR). Anyways: `$q.all(arrayOfPromises)` might be what you've been looking for.

Comment: Doesn't that change what the code does, though? The OP's code handles the promises *serially*. Doesn't `$q.all` handle them *in parallel* (like the standard `Promise.all`, which I believe was inspired by q's)?

Comment: yes, as I said, it does handle them in parallel. If that's really not desired, I'd just call .finally on the last value of .chain (like already suggested in another answer)